# Unable to store information as attributes in LDAP using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, apacheds

I'm trying to bind a java object as a set of attributes based on tutorial given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/objects/storing/dircontext.html)

```
//In the main() method of the program
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389/o=csRepository");
env.put(Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES, "sample.UserFactory");
 // Create the initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

User usr = new User("Goro");
ctx.bind("cn=Kill Bill, ou=employees", null, usr.getAttributes(""));
```

I have the User class as follows,

```
public class User implements DirContext {
    String employer;
    Attributes myAttrs;

    public User(String employer){
          this.employer = employer;
          myAttrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
          Attribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
          oc.add("extensibleObject");
          oc.add("top");

          myAttrs.put(oc);
          myAttrs.put("em", employer);
       }

    public Attributes getAttributes(String name) throws NamingException {
        if (!name.equals("")) {
            throw new NameNotFoundException();
        }
        return (Attributes) myAttrs.clone();
    }
    //other methods
}
```

When trying to bind I get,

```
javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16
- NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 2
    Add Request : Entry
    dn[n]: cn=Kill Bill, ou=employees,o=csRepository
    objectclass: extensibleObject
    objectclass: top
    cn: Kill Bill
    em: Goro
    ManageDsaITImpl Control
        Type OID    : '2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2'
        Criticality : 'false' ' : ERR_04269 ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID em does not exist!]; remaining name 'cn=Kill Bill, ou=employees'
```

Comment: why does it complain that OID em does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does it complain that OID em does not exist.

Because it doesn't. Using `extensibleObject` entitles you to add any existing attribute to the object. It doesn't entitle you to invent new attributes.

Comment: what are the existing attributes? If the objectclass is "extensibleObject", what are the attributes available. (My understanding is that attributes are specific to object classes)

Comment: You need to look at your LDAP schema. All possible attributes are defined in there, and all possible object classes, and all the attributes than can be used by a specific object class.